# Get redirect location (URL) from 3xx: Redirection HTTP response with Web Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

It's impossible to do in common web JS. For example, the follow code does not work as you may expect:

```js
fetch("https://crbug.com", { redirect: "manual" })
```

---

Well. But is it possible to do in web extension?

I need to get the redirect location for a URL. The `fetch` allows you only see if there was a redirect, and the final location (not intermediate ones, when the redirect count is more than 1) and only after the successful loading of the page (I don't want to download the page at all (even only HTTP headers too) – not to perform any connection with the page from `Location` of HTTP response header).

---

For example:

for `https://bit_ly/2ng6XCg`* I should get "http://crbug.com"

for "http://crbug.com" I should get "https://crbug.com"

for "https://crbug.com" I should get "https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list".

---

*replace `_` with `.`

Comment: You can do it by using webRequest API: chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect.addListener(console.log, {urls: ['<all_urls>']})

Comment: The problem is that I can't dynamically declare the blocking rule inside that listener: https://playcode.io/458409?tabs=script.js

Comment: Well then you'll have to declare the second listener for all URLs, and do it earlier - in onBeforeRequest event. Inside the redirect listener you'll set some global variable which you'll use in the second listener to decide what to do.

Comment: Thanks, it works. It's strange, but the dynamical listener removing  (`removeListener`) works without problems (adding – no (as I described it above)). https://playcode.io/458415?tabs=script.js

Comment: Try removing the beforerequest listener inside setTimeout.

Comment: Listener removing works well, I just mentioned my first comment.

Comment: Try that anyway. The idea is that API may not like it that there's no listener at the time it processes the return value.

Comment: Replacing it with ```setTimeout(() => { chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(onRequest); });``` breaks my testing code in ```(async () => { ... })();```

Comment: ```setTimeout(() => { chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(onRequest); resolve(blockedURL);});``` This one works. I have moved `resolve` function.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to wOxxOm, I have written that I wanted:

```
function getRedirect(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {

        let blockedURL;

        function onRequest(details) {
            //console.log("onBeforeRequest ", details);

            if (details.url === blockedURL) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(onRequest);
                    resolve(blockedURL);
                });
                return { cancel: true }; 
            }
        }
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(onRequest, { urls: ["<all_urls>"] }, ["blocking"]);

        function onRedirect(details) {
            //console.log("onBeforeRedirect", details);         
            blockedURL = details.redirectUrl;

            chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect.removeListener(onRedirect);
        }
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect.addListener(onRedirect, { urls: ["<all_urls>"] });

        fetch(url, { redirect: "follow" }).catch(console.warn);             
    }); 
}
```

Let's check the code:

```
(async () => {
    console.log("URL Redirects to ", await getRedirect("http://crbug.com"));                    
    // "URL Redirects to https://crbug.com" 

    console.log("URL Redirects to ", await getRedirect(await getRedirect("http://crbug.com"))); 
    // "URL Redirects to https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list"

    await fetch("http://crbug.com"); 
    // It works in common way (Fetch finished loading: GET "https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list")  
})();
```

In manifest.json:
`"permissions": ["<all_urls>", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking"]`

Comment: Todo: If the link have no redirects.